# Error 'e' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

Я, конечно не самый опытный программист но почему после компиляции этого кода:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
string s; 
cin >> s; 
int N = 0; 
for ( int i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; i++ ){ 
    if (s[i] != '_') 
    N++; 
    } 
string mas[N]; 
int i = 0; 
int j = 0; 
int d = 1;
while ( i < N ){ 
    while (s[j] != '_' && j < s.size()){ 
        if ( s[j] != s[d] )
        int e = d;
        mas[i] = mas[i] + s[j]; 
        d++;
        if ( d == '_' ){
            d = e + 1;
        }
    } 
    i++;
    j++; 
} 
cout << mas[i]; 
return 0; 
}
```

Dev выдает вот такую ошибку:[Error] 'e' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Смотрю, четкий ответ так и не дан. Словом, область видимости переменной, объявленной в инструкции `if`, ограничена этой инструкцией, так что объявление `int e = d` перестает быть видимым уже в следующей строчке.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (s[j] != '_' && j < s.size()){ 
    if ( s[j] != s[d] )
    int e = d;
```

Если `s[j] = s[d]`,
то `e` не будет объявлена. Объявите `е` вне цикла и в этом месте делайте присваивание.

Comment: Не важно, будет она объявлена или не будет. Область видимости `e` здесь - тело `if` и не более того.

Answer (score 1):

Вот это

```
        if ( s[j] != s[d] )
        int e = d;
        mas[i] = mas[i] + s[j];
```

фактически равно

```
        if ( s[j] != s[d] ){
          int e = d;
        }
        mas[i] = mas[i] + s[j];
```

Что здесь проверяется ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
string s; 
cin >> s; 
int N = 0; 
for ( int i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; i++ ){ 
    if (s[i] != '_') 
    N++; 
    } 
string mas[N]; 
int i = 0; 
int j = 0; 
int d = 1;
int e = 0; //объявим как все остальные переменные
while ( i < N ){ 
    while (s[j] != '_' && j < s.size()){ 
        if ( s[j] != s[d] )
        mas[i] = mas[i] + s[j]; 
        d++;
        if ( d == '_' ){
            d = e + 1;
        }
    } 
    i++;
    j++; 
} 
cout << mas[i]; 
return 0; 
}
```

программа уйдет в бесконечный цикл при работе, конечно же